# Is it possible to calculate joint densities or mass functions of random variables not sharing the same domain?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, independence

Is it possible to define joint probability densities/mass functions of random variables not sharing the same domain or having the same probability space or event space?

Comment: Short answer - no. You might be thinking of a coin flip and a die toss. Then the sample space is the $12$ possible pairs of outcomes. If you have some particular scenario in mind, [edit] the question to tell us what it is.

Comment: No. Your question boils down to, "Given only the marginals of $(X,Y)$, can we determine the joint distribution?" There are many possible joint distributions for a given pair of marginals (unless $X$ or $Y$ is constant), so this is an emphatic no.

Comment: The coin flip die toss problem works.